# Python/Pandas Dataframe - Calculate the difference of two far apart rows in a dataframe based on identifier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, diff

I am working on a dataframe in python (mostly pandas and numpy). Example is given below.

```
        Name   ID   Guess  Date  Topic                       Delta
    0    a     23    5     2019    1    (Person A's Guess in 2019 - Guess in 2018)
    1    a     23    8     2018    1
    2    c     7     7     2019    1    (Person C's Guess in 2019 - Guess in 2018)
    3    c     7     4     2018    1
    4    e     12    9     2018    1
    5    a     23    3     2020    2
```

I want to fill the empty column **Delta**, which is just the difference between the last guess on the same topic and the now updated guess. I am having troubles since I need to keep both the topic and the person's ID.

The dataset is fairly large (> 1mio. entries) which is why my approach to iterate over it did cause troubles when using the full dataframe.

I sorted the dataframe in they above way in order to try and solve it with .shift(); however I guess there must be a solution without sorting the df since I have enough identifiers (ID, Date, Topic).

```
for i in df.index:
    if df['ID'].iloc[i] == test['ID'].iloc[i+1]:
        df['Delta'].iloc[i+1] = df['Guess'].iloc[i+1] - test['Guess'].iloc[i]
    else:
         df['Delta'].iloc[i+1] = "NaN"
```

If anyone know a more efficient (maybe vectorized) solution for that problem, I would greatly appreciate the hints and help

Comment: Welcome, It looks like `df.groupby(['ID', 'Topic'])['Guess'].diff(-1)` or something similar

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This might have done the trick already.